# Can I install the Ruby Version Manager?

Tags: software-development, software-installation

Can I install the [Ruby Version Manager (RVM)](https://rvm.io/) on my Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Yes!

First, you'll need to install  `curl`, `git`, and `build-essential` for your operating system. If you don't know how to install software for your system please refer to [How do I install new software?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/387/46).

Next you need to download and run the bash script they provide.

```
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Next you can do one of two things.

1. Close and reopen your terminal session, or
2. Source the rvm script like so.

   ```
    $ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
   ```

Now you can check if RVM is installed by running the following command.

```
$ type rvm | head -n 1
rvm is a function
```

If you get a response like the above one RVM has been loaded and you can install a specific Ruby version. It is recommended that you install the latest stable release; which is Ruby 1.9.3 as of July 11, 2012.

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

Now the final the step is to tell RVM which version to use. In order to use a specific Ruby version for the duration of the current terminal session run the following.

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3
```

If you want to use that specific version every time you open a new terminal session though you are going to have to tell RVM to set it as the default Ruby. Like so.

```
$ rvm use --default 1.9.3
```

Congratulations, you have successfully installed RVM on your Raspberry Pi!

> *Note* `build-essential` is Debian's group for `gcc`, `g++`, `make` etc. Arch includes a similar group called `base-devel`.

Comment: Is this any different from installing on any other Linux machine?

Comment: @Jivings No, this works on all Linux machines.

Comment: In order to make this answer more Raspberry Pi specific, can you comment on the performance of Ruby on the Pi. Is this *worth* doing, or is it going to be unusably slow?

Comment: The make activity on RVM was quite slow as was compiling a Ruby. Make probably took 15 minutes on initial rvm install. Compiling took about an hour. After RVM and a ruby are installed, it is quite snappy.

Comment: +1 for getting me one step closer to RoR for the RPi. I haven't made a lot of effort towards it, as I don't have too much time to play with my Pi, but this answered my biggest question.

Comment: Rails "just works" on the Pi. It is a little slow (time rails takes 9s), but I've been using it for a little while now.

Comment: The correct package name is build-essential and not build-essentials.

Comment: A bit late to the game, but you can append `sudo` to the commands

Comment: I got an errror while executing the first command, also had to run this to add gpg keys: ***gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3***

Comment: @Vini.g.fer That error almost definitely also gives you a suggestion on how to fix it. Just do what it says ;)

Answer (score 1):

if it helps anyone using this i found this command on rasbain lite was needed

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
```